# expected expression before ‘va_list’

Tags: c, dynamic-programming, variadic-functions, markup

What does it mean by these error?

I was trying to build a simple _printf function but while trying to pass this va_list I am getting some expression errors.

main.c: In function ‘_printf’:

main.c:101:28: error: expected expression before ‘va_list’
count = _mySwit(c, va_list args, count);

main.c:101:17: error: too few arguments to function ‘_mySwit’
count = _mySwit(c, va_list args, count);

main.c:60:5: note: declared here
int _mySwit(char letter, va_list pargs, int cou)

##########################################################################

````
{
    char leter, *str;
    int i = 0;
    
    switch (letter)
    {
        case 'c':
        leter = (char) va_arg(pargs, int);
        _putchar(leter);
        cou++;
        break;
        case 's':
        str = va_arg(pargs, char *);
        while(str[i] != '\0')
        {    
            _putchar(str[i]);
            cou++; }
        i = 0;
        break;
        default:
        break;
        
    }
   
    
    return (cou);
}

char _printf(char *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    char *string, *inStr;
    int inarg, count;
    
    va_start(args, format);
    
    if (*format == '%')
    {
        char c = *format++;
        
        count = _mySwit(c, va_list args, count);
        *format++; }
    else
        _putchar(*format);
        count++;
        
    
    
    return (count);
}```
##################################################################
````

Comment: That's not how you define or call a varargs function...

Comment: Consult a high quality C reference or tutorial.

Comment: very probably you forgot to `#include <stdargs.h>`

Answer (score 0):

When passing the va_list, typing it `count = _mySwit(c, args, count);` that way works instead of. `count = _mySwit(c, va_list args, count);`